# Bot Framework Composer - Orchestrator - Value cannot be null. (Parameter ‘modelFolder’)

Tags: botframework, azure-qna-maker, azure-language-understanding

I'm trying to make Orchestrator work inside Bot Framework Composer. I'm able to install the Orchestrator extension from packages. When I try to run the bot from inside the composer, I'm getting a **self signed certificate in certificate chain** error.

However, when I run the bot as a solution from Visual Studio it runs well and the bot starts well in Emulator. When I try to trigger an intent that is using Orchestrator, I'm getting the below error.

> Value cannot be null. (Parameter ‘modelFolder’)

Are we supposed to manually download the NLP model that orchestrator uses and place it somewhere ? I'm facing similar issue when I deploy this to Azure. Am stuck at this for a while now. Any help is deeply appreciated.

I've tried a similar setup on my personal machine and don't see the certificate error. The error seems to be because of Firewall/VPN issues at work. Locally, the model gets downloaded to AppData under Users folder and the model path is pointed to that location. Local execution works. I've copied the model data to the project folder and provided a relative path to publish on Azure. While even this setup works locally, however when I publish to Azure I receive failed to load or find model error. Below is a screenshot of the same from Test Web Chat
[image]
The catch is that the model exists at the exact place being pointed out by the bot. However, its not able to locate it. I've seen couple of Github issues discussing about the x64 and x86 bit app service regarding Orchestrator. I've deployed this to a x64 App Service with 3.5 GB memory.

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't need to do this. Have you verified that at no point in the process you created your own certificate for something in your project?

Comment: Yes. I haven't created any certificates nor do I see any in the project folder. I've updated my questions with what else I've tried.

Comment: You could try setting `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0` as an environment variable in a terminal and then launching Composer from the terminal. Then try again and see what happens.

Comment: With this setting it worked. Composer stopped looking at certificates. One more mistake I did was deploying from Visual Studio. Somehow I might not have chosen the right build settings. Now everything works well